# adding some elements in matlab with known Index

Tags: arrays, matlab, addition

I have one array like below:

```
Array = [21.2, 13.6, 86.2, 54.6, 76, 34, 78, 12, 90, 4];
```

Now I want to add `Array` values from the first index to the fourth index, and from the seventh index to the tenth.

I wrote this code but it did not work correctly.

```
s = 0
for I=1:10
if 1<=I<=4 | I>6
s = s + Array(I);
end
end
```

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: I want do this: 21.2+13.6+86.2+54.6+12+90+4

Comment: Do ***NOT*** use names of built-in functions for your own variables, you're bound to wind up in hard to debug errors. So don't call your `sum` `sum`, don't call your `mean` `mean` and don't call a loop index `i`.

Comment: total = sum(arr([1:4,7:numel(arr)])

Comment: @PTRK why use `numel(arr)`? There's a 3 letter built-in to give you the final point in an array...

Comment: @Adriaan I was not sure that `end` may work in that case.

Comment: @PTRK It would. Given the OP specified "tenth" not "last", I'd use `10` anyway

Comment: @Wolfie Woopsi. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement it without any kind of loop that may slow your code. To make those sums, you just need to use 'sum'. For further help, please read [this](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html). In your case, I'd do the following:

```
a = [21.2, 13.6, 86.2, 54.6, 76, 34, 78, 12, 90, 4];
b = sum(a(1:4))+sum(a(8:end));
```

Comment: Small detail: `1<=I<=4 | I>6` would translate to `1:4` and `7:end`, not `8:end`.

Comment: You can also do `sum(a([1:4,7:end]))`, or even `sum(a)-a(5:6)` ... though that last one doesn't seem very clear... :)

Comment: Yeah, I realized about it, but in the comments he specifies that he wants to add the elements `21.2+13.6+86.2+54.6+12+90+4`, which does not correspond to `1<=I<=4 | I>6` but to `1<=I<=4 | I>7`. Regarding your second comment, it is perfectly valid too! @CrisLuengo